# Rotating DIV spins slowly on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I think I overlooked something. This is a very simple spin-the-bottle game.

Javascript/jQuery

```
$('.bottle').on('click', function(e) {
    this.removeAttribute('style');
    var deg = 3000 + Math.round(Math.random() * 500);
    var css = '-webkit-transform: rotate(' + deg + 'deg);';

    this.setAttribute(
        'style', css
    );
});
```

CSS:

```
.bottle {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url(img/bottle.png);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 6s ease-out;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="bottle"></div>
```

This works perfectly on the first click of the bottle. But starting from the second click, the spin is very very slow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/sMcAN/

```
var i = 1;
$('.bottle').on('click', function(e) {
this.removeAttribute('style');
var deg = 3000 + Math.round(Math.random() * 500);
deg = ((-1) ^ i) * deg;

var css = '-webkit-transform: rotate(' + deg + 'deg);';
this.setAttribute('style', css);
i++;
});​
```

Another update : http://jsfiddle.net/sMcAN/2/

Comment: +1 for a working demo. @MartinLyder: The thing I would keep an eye on on any solution is the continues increase/decrease of the degrees as eventualy I would assume you reach a out of memory exception. I don't know if the max degrees is a max int/long or decimal, etc...

Comment: Oh i found an error, the "deg" is rising after each atempt.. So the logo in the demo is increasing in speed after every click...

Comment: @MartinLyder : See the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sMcAN/2/) , The rotation direction changes in each click here...

Comment: I have a second question though: If i make a slider which change the offset value of 3000 to a variable between 500 and 3500. The change in speed first work after second spin/click?

Answer (score 3):

This is because at first, you are going from 0 to a value over 3000. But then, the value is always within 3000 - so the difference is not big  enough and it still takes the 6 seconds you have defined.

One solution would be to make sure that you offset the value and make it different by few thousand each time.

```
var i = 0, offset = [2000, 4000, 6000, 3000, 5000, 1000];

$('.bottle').on('click', function(e) {
  this.removeAttribute('style');

  var deg = offset[i] + Math.round(Math.random() * 500);
  i++;
  if (i > 5) {
    i = 0;
  }

  var css = '-webkit-transform: rotate(' + deg + 'deg);';

  this.setAttribute(
    'style', css
 );
});​
```

Comment: +1 for explaining why the rotation behaves the way it does. I assume OP expected the degrees to be accumulative while it is not. To keep spinning the bottle forward it would be sweet if somehow the final degrees after the first spin can be set to be the new 0 position of the div and as such a new spin with the same deg setting would keep work and spinning forward.

Comment: Yes François Wahl good point. That would be a great feature :) And thanks Dakdad this is a great way to make the bottle more random like...

Comment: I think i will end up making a solution where the user will have the possibility to set the offset by a slider (speed, power or something like that)

Answer (score 0):

```
math.round(math.random() * 1000);
```

Try that